# For each cell (Match Row) Then....Multiple Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner when it comes to Excel VBA and I'm completely lost.

I want the macro to partial match either "Buick", "Chevrolet", or "Pontiac". The matches in Column D "SheetJS" should be copied to Column AA in "Sheet1". The matches in Column E "SheetJS" should be copied to Column AH in "Sheet1". The matches in Column F ("SheetJS") should be copied to Column AL in "Sheet1".

I have other ranges but once I get this code working, I should be able to get code the rest.

```
Sub Extract_Data_Buick()
    For Each cell In Sheets("SheetJS").Range("D1:D200")
        matchrow = cell.Row

        If (cell.Value = "*Buick*" Or cell.Value = "*Chevrolet*" Or cell.Value = "*Pontiac*") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA" & matchrow).Value = cell.Value

        End If
    Next

    For Each cell In Sheets("SheetJS").Range("E1:E200")
        matchrow = cell.Row

        If (cell.Value = "*Buick*" Or cell.Value = "*Chevrolet*" Or cell.Value = "*Pontiac*") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & matchrow).Value = cell.Value

        End If
    Next

    For Each cell In Sheets("SheetJS").Range("F1:F200")
        matchrow = cell.Row

        If (cell.Value = "*Buick*" Or cell.Value = "*Chevrolet*" Or cell.Value = "*Pontiac*") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AL" & matchrow).Value = cell.Value

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any tips will be greatly appreciated!

Update 01.11.20

I have also tried but I still can't get the code to work.

```
Sub Extract_Data_Buick()
    For Each cell In Sheets("SheetJS").Range("D1:D200")
        matchrow = cell.Row

        if (cell.value like "*Buick*") Or (cell.Value = "*Chevrolet*") Or (cell.Value = "*Pontiac*") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA" & matchrow).Value = cell.Value

        End If
    Next

    For Each cell In Sheets("SheetJS").Range("E1:E200")
        matchrow = cell.Row

        if (cell.value like "*Buick*") Or (cell.Value = "*Chevrolet*") Or (cell.Value = "*Pontiac*") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH" & matchrow).Value = cell.Value

        End If
    Next

    For Each cell In Sheets("SheetJS").Range("F1:F200")
        matchrow = cell.Row

        if (cell.value like "*Buick*") Or (cell.Value = "*Chevrolet*") Or (cell.Value = "*Pontiac*") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AL" & matchrow).Value = cell.Value

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really want to put these values in their respective rows on the other sheet or do you actually need to put them in a list on that sheet? Maybe, to really help you get some fast coding going it is best to include a screenshot with what you have got now and one with your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

don't use

```
cell.Value = "*Buick*"
```

but please use

```
if instr ("Buick", cell.value)> 0 then ...
```

or

```
if (cell.value like "*Buick*") then ....
```

refer:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Comment: I had tried If (cell.Value Like "*Buick*") Or (cell.Value Like "*Chevrolet*")  Or (cell.Value Like "*Pontiac*") Then but it didn't work

Comment: You are trying to match part of the string,so you must use * in the expression as I wrote

Comment: I tried If (cell.Value Like "*Buick*") Or (cell.Value Like "*Chevrolet*") Or (cell.Value Like "*Pontiac*") But it only works when I use 2 not 3. Such as "*Buick*" or "*Chevrolet*". For some reason the * aren't showing up.